# What is the best way to get IIS for XP Pro SP2 if you don't have the CD?

Tags: .net, iis

I have a work laptop that was purchased new, but it came without the CD. It has XP Pro, but it did not come with IIS installed. This looked to be a good approach:

http://ezinearticles.com/?Guide---How-To-Install-IIS-on-Windows-XP-SP2-Without-CD&id=416853

However, I wanted to check here to see if there were alternative solutions that anyone could recommend, and to check if any of the free .NET developer tools possibly come with IIS as a bundled package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have your install disk - check to see if there's a directory called C:\Windows\Options\i386.  The IIS components are located in IIS6.CAB.

You can also download the full Windows XP SP2 download which should have the IIS6.CAB file in it: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=049C9DBE-3B8E-4F30-8245-9E368D3CDB5A&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand concerns over a question being "not programming related", please tell me how many .NET Web application developers are programming without IIS? I would argue that this would make it programming related, wouldn't you? There is nothing wrong with the question -- I mean seriously, I want to know how to get the damn thing so that I can start programming .NET Web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You often find with computers that have windows preinstalled that the windows installer files are loaded in a directory on the hard disk somewhere. If this is the case all you need to do is burn that directory onto a DVD. Failing that I would suggest going back to where you purchased your PC from and demanding one, after all you paid for it.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggesstions are all good ones. There is probably an i386 folder somewhere that has all the installation files you need.

As an aside, I don't think Microsoft is going to let anyone redistribute IIS due to the risk of modified binaries.

Comment: It is best not to reference "above suggestions" on Stackoverflow as your answer will move up and down the list based on people's votes.